# Should I write a new application in Flex4/Spark if performance is a bigger consideration than skinning?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I've worked extensively with MX and Spark frameworks and both work fine for me. I am about to start a very large project in Flex where speed and file size are going to be critical factors. I am not going to use Adobe Catalyst.

Is there any reason I should use Spark for this application rather than MX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any reason I should use Spark for this application rather
>   than MX?

Adobe has stated that Spark is the future.  The MX line is receiving no new components; and many expect to the be deprecated at some future point.

Spark also provides a significantly more flexible skinning architecture.

Spark components are architected in a way that is supposed to be more light weight; sort of like a "Pay As You Go" architecture, so you aren't dragging lots of functionality along that you don't need.  A good example of this is that scrollbars are separate from containers.

Spark also provides you with greater Flexibility for deployments.  Only spark components are supported on Mobile devices, for example.

If speed and file size are critical factors, you may want to reconsider your use of Flex, though.  There are a bunch of alternate ActionScript frameworks such as Reflex, that are written for simplicity and performance.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know that MX is being abandoned but it already has everything I need and the skinning architecture isn't important to this particular project. I have read in several place that Spark can be significantly more heavy than MX, even Adobe admits it: [link](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2011/04/migratory-foul-performance-problems-migrating-from-flex-3-x-to-flex-4-x.html). Are there any other factors I am missing?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion on Reflex, I hadn't heard of it before. It looks like a nice framework but it is lacking a few components that I need. Would it make sense to mix this framework with Flex components or would that defeat the purpose?

Comment: I'm not sure about mixing Reflex w/ Flex Components.  In theory it seems possible; but not something I've experimented with.  I'm not sure what else you are missing.